# How to stop printing null in an array

Tags: java, arrays, null

How do I stop my program from printing out the positions of the array that are null, when I'm going through an array and printing the positions out?

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
  System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

It's simple like this, but how do I stop it from printing out the positions that are null?
Thanks in advance for an answer to this simple question...

Comment: Are you sure (depending on your expected cases) that it's not better to AVOID inserting some null values in it?

Comment: I mostly wanted this to make it easier if I have an array that is longer than I need it to be, making the leftover positions null, so that I don't have to print them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
   if (array[i]!=null) {
     System.out.println(array[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy solution!

Comment: @NoobUnChained The multiline-braceless-if is generally considered bad practice however

Comment: What was the downvote for ? Please downvote with comments so that the poster can understand what's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 3):

You just use the i of the for loop to check inside the array what the value is.
I hope this is what you needed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  if(array[i] != null)
  {
    System.out.print(array[i]);

  }
}
```